# encrypting multiple variables with AES_ENCRYPT in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, sql-insert

What's the correct syntax for a SQL statement like this:

```
$insert = ("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (1,AES_ENCRYPT('$email',UNHEX('F3229A0B371ED2D9441B830D21A390C3'))),(1,AES_ENCRYPT('$password',UNHEX('F3229A0B371ED2D9441B830D21A390C3')));");
```

I'm trying to add two variables to the same row of a db, both of them encrypted. The `$email` and `$password` variables are inputs from a web form, but you probably guessed that. I get an error message saying there's an unexpected comma which must be the one between the two values.

Comment: This code is vulnerable for SQL injection. You need to use prepared statements.

Comment: Know of a tutorial for inserting multiple variables to a db using prepared statements, with some encrypted and some not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong SQL,

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (
  AES_ENCRYPT('$email',UNHEX('F3229A0B371ED2D9441B830D21A390C3')),
  AES_ENCRYPT('$password',UNHEX('F3229A0B371ED2D9441B830D21A390C3'))
)
```

Comment: I get this error: Error: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1. This is the command: `$insert = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('$email',UNHEX('F3229A0B371ED2D9441B830D21A390C3')),(AES_ENCRYPT('$password',UNHEX('F3229A0B371ED2D9441B830D21A390C3'))";
`

Comment: Why you want to add `(` at the line 3?

Comment: You mean the one right before `AES_ENCRYPT('$password'` right? I didn't realize it was in there. I've taken it out but still get same error message. Something about a double quote mark

Comment: double quote is fine, Can you edit your latest code?

Comment: Here's the most recent code: `$insert = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('$email',UNHEX('F3229A0B371ED2D9441B830D21A390C3')),AES_ENCRYPT('$password',UNHEX('F3229A0B371ED2D9441B830D21A390C3'))";
`

Comment: You missing one `)` and the end

Comment: Yes, that was correct. My next problem is that it's adding three rows to the db instead of adding the new user to a single row.